# How to use code to add items dynamically to UI and position them correctly in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, combobox

Let's say I have a UI like this:

[image]

I want the Subject combo-box to determine how many Difficulties combo-box and Number of questions it should have.
For example, if the Subject combo-box has a variable of 5, it will add 5 more combo-boxes and line edits nicely and neatly like this: [image]

How do I implement this, with layouts ( in c++ ).

Later, I will add more child combo-boxes like this
[image]

So, I can not use Grid Layout, also the window size has to be able to change dynamically due to that the number of items in it will fluctuate.

Comment: I am using qt 5.7 by the way

Comment: Since you may end up with a tree of items, consider using an editable `QTreeView` with a `QAbstractItemModel` that inserts/removes child items when the value for the number of questions changes. You can have delegate `QComboBox`es and you will end up with a much cleaner solution.

Comment: Could you be more specific on how to do that ?

Comment: I am suggesting that you use a [Tree View](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/modelview.html#3-1-treeview) since it is better suited for displaying dynamic trees. In my opinion, any other solution will have limitations/problems. For example, what if the user wanted to have 100 questions, of course you wouldn't resize the window and add 100 `QComboBox`es/`QLineEdit`s yourself, in the case of a tree view however this is not a problem since it is scroll-able.

Comment: Ok I see your point. Would you mind sending me some examples where QComboBox and QLabel are added dynamically to the QTreeView ? I'm new to this platform and not sure how to go about it.

Comment: Basically, start with subclassing `QAbstractItemModel`, test your model in a view without `QComboBox`es first. in your model's `setData`, you should add/remove child items. When you get that all working with your persistent storage (if needed). subclass `QStyledItemDelegate` to have `QComboBox`es in the columns where you need to.

Comment: Try implementing that, and if you get into problems. Please ask a new question (as this is not related to the current question) :)

Comment: Would you mind giving me some actual examples with codes ? I know it's a lot to ask but lots of documentations online are very unclear. I'm very new to this platform and still figuring out how to implement what you described.

Answer (score 0):

Try a QStackedWidget with a widget and a layout and a set of child widgets for each alternative configuration you need.

Comment: Would you mind showing me how to dynamically implement that ?